# jQuery Uncaught TypeError in $(selector).on()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am getting the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: ((jQuery.event.special[handleObj.origType] || (intermediate value)).handle || handleObj.handler).apply is not a function

This is my code and it's somewhere in between the `beforeSend` and the `success` calls that the error is happening:

```
$('#main-container').on('click', '#sign-in-btn', function (event) {
    var username = $('#username-textbox').val();
    var password = $('#password-textbox').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: '/login',
        method: 'POST',

        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ":" + password));
        },

        success: function (data) {
        }
    });

    event.preventDefault();
});
```

I also tried to put inside  a `$(document).ready(function () { ... }` call and I get the exact same error.

Comment: you have to include `jquery` before and put it in `$( document ).ready(function() {...});`

Comment: Try to use `Pause on exception` feature in Chrome Dev Tools and go through call stack up with exploring variables

Comment: @ozil Even the first line won't be executed if jQuery was not included or `ready` wrapper was not implemented.

Comment: I wrapped it inside a $(document).ready() call and I still get the exact same error. Editing the question to include that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Having the event function return `false` fixed it because the error was somewhere during the propagation of the event and if an event returns `false` then `event.stopPropagation()` is "called".