# jQuery onclick registration error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button that I want to attach a click listener to, but everytime the code runs, it throws a console error

`jquery.js:4435 Uncaught TypeError: ((n.event.special[g.origType] || (intermediate value)).handle || g.handler).apply is not a function`

Here's the js code that triggers the error, the first line runs fine, the second line is the one that causes the error

```
$toolbar.off('click', '.btn-save'); // $toolbar is assigned $("#toolbar") on init           
$toolbar.on('click', '.btn-save', function(e){
    saveData(0);
});
```

What confuses me is, if I run that bit of code manually through the console, I get no errors

Here's the HTML

```
<div class="row" id="toolbar">
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-save">Save</button>
    <button type="button" id="btnCancel" class="btn btn-default btn-cancel">Cancel</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want help debugging you should supply enough code for someone else to run easily. Making a jsfiddle is a good way to go ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught TypeError: ((x.event.special\[i.origType\] || (intermediate value)).handle || i.handler).apply is not a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32231036/uncaught-typeerror-x-event-speciali-origtype-intermediate-value-handl)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have found the problem, below my listeners, there's an unrelated listener that I attached

`$(document).on("click", "#btn-back", Views.Editor.close);`

The problem here is that `Views.Editor.close` is the wrong method name.
When I changed the method name, the error disappears

I didn't realize that an unrelated listener can affect others

Comment: Stumbled upon this very same Problem in Internet Explorer 11. It turns out there was an invalid event listener that I seem to have overlooked or just forgotten : `.on("click", ".")`. Indeed it seems that even only one invalid listener may break the functionality of the others, at least if script execution is set to halt on every exception. Note this error also occurs with the development / full Version of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Ah. looks like you may have your JQuery params wrong if I've understood the question/ what you're trying to do.

DOM events should be appended to items on

html:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <button id="save-btn-id" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-save">Save</button>
    <button type="button" id="btnCancel" class="btn btn-default btn-cancel">Cancel</button>
</div>
</div>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#save-btn-id').click(function(evt) {
    saveData(0);
  });
});
```

Comment: doesn't work either, I've tried all 3 types of click assignment that I know of, $btn.click(func), $btn.on('click', func), and $toolbar.on('click', '#btn', func);

Answer (score 0):

Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/jorge182/a1y9abcj/2/

```
toolbar =  $("#toolbar")


$(toolbar).off('click', '.btn-save'); // $toolbar is assigned $("#toolbar") on init           
$(toolbar).on('click', '.btn-save', function(e){
    saveData();
});


function saveData(){
   alert();
}
```

Comment: hmm, for some reason doesn't seem to work when I try it on jsfiddle

Comment: Probably is code legacy, and you dont want to go very deep on it, but i dont see too much sense in deactivate one action in one line and activate in the next line...I would remove the line where set button off

Answer (score 0):

From what I see at jQuery's API docs for their .off() function & in the code example above, it looks like the function isn't being passed as the 3rd parameter to the .off() function. So it's possible that the jQuery library is complaining that it can't find a function to remove it.

See: http://api.jquery.com/off/

Try this & see if it helps:

```
function clickListener(e){
    saveData(0);
};

$toolbar.off('click', '.btn-save', clickListener);
$toolbar.on('click', '.btn-save', clickListener);
```

Comment: I just tried that, unfortunately it doesn't work. I even tried commenting out the .off() command, and it's still the same result

Comment: The code runs OK at this jsfiddle with v. 2.2.1: https://jsfiddle.net/briankueck/75ucysvx/

Comment: When looking at this link: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.js I found the code on line 4731-2. You may have to put a debugger before those lines - in your localhost jquery.js file - to see what the values appear in this line of code: "ret = ( ( jQuery.event.special[ handleObj.origType ] || {} ).handle || handleObj.handler ).apply( matched.elem, args );"