# How to resolve this error type 'Uncaught TypeError: (...) is not a function'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, error-handling, typeerror, getscript

*I am aware of the another question like this on stackoverflow and have looked at it, but it doesn't answer/resolve my situation that I'm having from which the error has occurred.*

I'm trying to make both scripts, `embed.js` (plugin) & `more-content-arrow.js` (my script) work properly on the page when the document loads. When and if I remove either script, one or the other will work but not both scripts together. When the page finishes loading first, it will load the `more-content-arrow.js` properly, then when it is trigged again by a scrolling event, it will give off this error message in the console browser:

```
VM249 embed.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: ((fe.event.special[s.origType] || (intermediate value)).handle || s.handler).apply is not a function
    at dispatch (VM249 embed.js:2)
    at m.handle (VM249 embed.js:2)
```

I tried to resolve it by adding a `jQuery.noConflict();`, but that doesn't work as I assume it could be a conflict between the two scripts. The only way I found out to get rid of the error message is removing one of the two scripts file or removing `$.getScript(...)`, but I don't want to do that. I want to be able to keep both scripts running properly in the page.

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //jQuery.noConflict();
  $.getScript("more-content-arrow.js", function(){
    alert("arrow script loaded and executed.");
  });
});
```

I recreated a jsfiddle with the uncaught type error here:

https://jsfiddle.net/wr6cc2ct/2/

Comment: Your code seems to be working in the fiddle. I ran it and just got the message box without any error. Of course as @yezzz suggests, I removed one of the extra embed.js s. So maybe that's the reason.

Comment: @jrook guessing you did not scroll

Comment: I thought that was the reason as well, but looks like it wasn't, so i removed my answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught TypeError: ((x.event.special\[i.origType\] || (intermediate value)).handle || i.handler).apply is not a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32231036/uncaught-typeerror-x-event-speciali-origtype-intermediate-value-handl)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error appears it be in your `more-content-arrow.js` file, you were passing an integer as a third argument which is not a handler, here is the jquery doc for [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    if (!footerIsVisible) {
        $('.bounce').fadeIn(300);
    }
}); // <--- removed integer here.
```

#### Update

Alternatively, you can use `event.stopPropagation();` along with re-ordering the `jquery.unevent.js` script **after** the `ember.js` script.

```
$(window).on('scroll', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if (!footerIsVisible) {
        $('.bounce').fadeIn(300);
    }
}, 800);
```

Comment: To my surprise, the error disappeared, but I need jquery.event.js to work too as it delays the amount of time the scroll event hasn't been called (800 ms in this case) and for the arrow to be hidden when the footer is in view. Also, it's perfectly valid to use that as jquery.event.js supports this mark up. Have a look here: http://yckart.github.io/jquery.unevent.js/

Comment: @TheAmazingKnight this is probably because you're binding it to the window object, try it with a selector (like an `id` or `class`)!

Comment: I see. But to no avail it is still doesn't work with body tag, class or id, only window. Trying to think of other solutions to make this work. Hm.

Comment: Okay, a couple of things I would recommend; first, move your `embed.js` dependancy above the `jquery.unevent` script. Then pass the event into the `on()` callback and call `event.stopPropagation();` to avoid any event bubbling issues!

Comment: Thank you so much. The above comment helped. Do I mark this entire answer as correct? or maybe you want to append to the above answer? I got it to work without removing the integer at the end. Thanks again.