# Getting this jquery error on document click (intermediate value)).handle || c.handler).apply is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to see which function is causing this error? Or which button I'm binding to that isn't on the page? Ive got 7+ js files linking to my php page and I can't seem to find which binding, or missing function is causing this error.

I checked out this link [uncaught type error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32231036/uncaught-typeerror-x-event-speciali-origtype-intermediate-value-handl)  and found that It could be two different issues. But it doesn't tell me how to search for the issue. Chrome usually will give me a line number when I've got syntax error or otherwise.