# Jquery $(window) pass option with { passive: false }

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am getting following error:

```
Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive
```

from this code:

```
$(window).on("DOMMouseScroll mousewheel wheel", _methods._handler_window_mousewheel);
```

from what i was able to find, it seems that solution should be adding { passive: false } as options, but i am stuck on that, since i dont know how to do that :/
 Basically like this:

```
document.addEventListener('touchstart', handler, {passive: false});
```

but when i do this:

```
 $(window).on("DOMMouseScroll mousewheel wheel", _methods._handler_window_mousewheel, { passive: false});
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: ((w.event.special[a.origType] || {}).handle || a.handler).apply is not a function
```

My Jquery knowledge is pretty limited, so thats where i hit wall. Thanks for any help.

Comment: could be related to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32231036/uncaught-typeerror-x-event-speciali-origtype-intermediate-value-handl. can you check if `_methods._handler_window_mousewheel` is not `undefined`

Comment: the functions exists and is called properly. I believe the issue is with the passive options, which i am not able to set.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42101723/unable-to-preventdefault-inside-passive-event-listener)